# «Вроде как» обособляется или нет?

Tags: вводные-слова

Ввести налог депутаты решили, вроде как, по опыту других стран...
«Вроде как» вводное или нет?

Answer (score 1):

**вро́де как**

**I союз разг.**

Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения или части предложения (в которых выражается приблизительное сходство), соответствуя по значению сл.: *как будто, словно, будто.*

**II част. разг.**

1.
Употребляется при выражении неуверенности или предположительности высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: *по-видимому, вероятно, наверное.*

2.
Употребляется при выражении условной предположительности высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: *как бы, будто бы.*

**Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.**

***В этом предложении, на мой взгляд, выражение  обособлять не следует, вводным оно не является.***

*Ввести налог депутаты решили вроде как по опыту других стран...*

Также надо отметить, что разговорное *вроде как* с трудом вписывается в данный контекст, поэтому предложение лучше всего перестроить.